# How to store text field of toast into a database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have been writing this code for getting location. How to store `mg` in `SQLite` database of `android`?

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {                                   
        String mg = " Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude:" + location.getLatitude();                                                              
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),mg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I have tried this:-

```
public void locate(View view) { 
    //to insert 
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("mgs",locationtext.getText().toString()); 
    long id = mSQLiteDb.insert("Location",null,cv);
   //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(id),Toast.‌​LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It did not store, so I doubt that I can we store the text field of Toast method?

Comment: have you tried searching before asking?

Comment: what have you tried to do that ?

Comment: public void locate(View view) {  //to insert
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

        cv.put("mgs",locationtext.getText().toString());
        
        long id =mSQLiteDb.insert("Location",null,cv);
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(id),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: ok, and what is the problem with it?

Comment: could not store.so my  doubt is that can we store the text field of Toast method?

Comment: you can't store a text field, as it is a `View`. You should store the string.

Answer (score 0):

Methods `void ContentValues.put(String key, <type> value)` are used to save value with its key, where `<type>` stands for `'Short`, `Long`, `Double`, `Integer`, `String`,`Boolean`,`Float`, `Byte` or `Byte[]`. Stored values can be then retrieved by method `Object ContentValues.get(String key)` with further casting result to your type, or  by convenient methods like `Boolean ContentValues.getAsBoolean(String key)`. See details at [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html).

So, it seems that it is impossible to `put` Location object directly into `ContentValues`. I don't think that `Location.toString()` could help because this method usually returnі the internal representation of the object like that (see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#toString())):

> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

It could be advised to put latitude and longitude (and all other necessary `Location`  parameters) as the numerical or string values. Other approach is to create your own class inherited from `Location`, and to override `toString` method to return all necessary data in one string. However, IMHO it could be more useful to save latitude, longitude and other necessary things by separate values.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for my problem and set as:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {                                   
    String mg = " Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude:" + location.getLatitude();                                                              
    textView.setText(mg);
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("column name", textView.getText().toString());
    sqliteDatabase.insert("table name", null, contentValues);
}
```